# Curly brackets are not scaling correct in MathJax in .js file

Tags: javascript, mathjax, brackets, curly-braces

I am currently writing an equation using MathJax in a .js-file for a website.

The equation is written using this code (every backslash that normally would be used in MathJax requires 2 backslash in my .js):

```
    var M_p_eq = "$$ M_p = \\left\\{ \\begin{matrix}\\begin{array}{r l} \\begin{matrix}\\begin{array}{r} \\frac{t^2}{\\gamma_m}\\left(0.29\\sigma_{R4}+0.16\\sigma_{R1}\\right) \\end{array}\\end{matrix} & \\text{if}\\; \\rho = 0\\% \\\\ \\begin{matrix}\\begin{array}{r} \\frac{t^2}{\\gamma_m}\\left(0.29\\sigma_{R4}+0.16\\sigma_{R1}\\right) + \\\\ \\frac{A_s\\,f_{yk}\\left(d-0.048\\,t\\right)}{\\gamma_s} \\end{array}\\end{matrix} & \\text{if}\\; 0\\% <  \\rho \\leq 0.15\\% \\\\ \\begin{matrix}\\begin{array}{r} \\frac{0.5(\\sigma_{R1}\\,\\sigma_{R4})(t-t_{ux})(0.28\\,t_{ux}+0.33\\,t)}{\\gamma_m} + \\\\ \\frac{\\sigma_{R4}(t-t_{ux})(0.11\\,t_{ux}+0.5\\,t)}{\\gamma_m} + \\\\ \\frac{A_s\\,f_{yk}(d-0.039\\,t_{ux})}{\\gamma_s} \\end{array}\\end{matrix} & \\text{if}\\; \\rho > 0.15\\% \\end{array}\\end{matrix} \\right. $$"
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

As you can see the curly brackets are not covering the whole matrix and as such it is not vertically centered (M_p is not aligned with the tip of the curl).

If I simply exchange the `\right\{` with `\right(` I get the following results for regular brackets:

[image]

As you can see the bracket is covering the whole matrix. and everything is fine, except I want it to be curly brackets!

Can anyone help me?

Note: I have also tried using `\left\lbrace` instead of `\left\{` without luck.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Using MathJax's own demo I get the correct result. The issue is probably in the .js-file, so it might be hard to help me out. :(